# Dev++ Sum of a Series "cannot be used as a function"

Tags: c++, function

```
/*
  David Ballantyne
  10/03/13
  sum of a series

*/
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

//no global constants

//no functioning prototypes

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){
    //Declare Variables
    short n,knwn,num,sum=0;

    //prompt user
    cout<<"input a number grater than 0";
    cin>>n;

    //Calculate
    for( int num=1;num<=n;sum+=num++);


    //known
    knwn =(n(n+1))/2;

    //output

    cout<<"the sum of the series is"<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"the sum of the known series is"<<knwn<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

on line 30 for know it says 'n' cannot be used as a function

I'm in an intro c++ class and having a little difficulty I'm sure the solution is simple but I can't seem to fnd it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left out the multiplication operator.  Change `knwn =(n(n+1))/2;` to `knwn =(n * (n+1))/2;`.